# Selenium Grid - testsession

Tags: selenium, grid

Is there a way to retrieve the ipaddress of the jenkins server from where the execution is invoked? I am trying to print this in the hub log for selenium grid.

I have tried to check the testsession class. but unable to get the information where the requestor details are stored.

Can any one help on this.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I want to retrieve the requestor details.The machine address from where the connection/execution request is sent to selenium grid hub.